# How to change the response.redirect URL value?

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

> I send value to another page by response.redirect the URL have the
>   value and it is very too long :

=">http://x.elarabygroup.com/SiteLogin.aspx?token=1ddd11ekkHDLSAFJ;AHFJEHJKFKJFJHF#*=*

> I want to hide or display another url as
>   http://x.elarabygroup.com/playgame/

```
Response.Redirect("http://x.elarabygroup.com/SiteLogin.aspx?token=" + respnse);
```

Comment: Do you *need* to send that token via the URL or could you use Session to keep it server-side and out of the URL?

Comment: If that URL is part of your application then you can keep the value server-side.  If it isn't, then you have to send the value somehow, and with a redirect the only way is via the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use session instead if you want to hide it:

Assuming both pages are on the same domain of course.

```
Session["token"] = "CAACgVEYG6y4BAPpCA576tZCOVTaiStohQHcFMj8TnkYDiIBWnuQjoMSRMSjmTlZCK0JhdyWP8MYiFQELLGUMht07vKZCVLaxz7gBASydeG5PqBB9dypqvEh7tyTR1nZCRvZBITNEcnkDj00pFxNGKfi9v8U5UkVAjQlLuY08aVANUgZC9dZAi852216uCsTgpcZD#=";
Response.Redirect("http://x.elarabygroup.com/SiteLogin.aspx");
```

in **SiteLogin.aspx**, check for the token.

Comment: `$_SESSION['token']`?  Single-quoted strings?

Comment: I don't do asp, but the same concept applies, anyway I'll change it.